# java String hashcode caching mechanism

Tags: java, hashcode

Looking at Java's `String` class we can see that hash code is cached after first evaluation.

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Where `hash` is an instance variable. I have a question, why do we need that `h` extra variable?

Comment: It is written like this to ensure that the `String` class is thread-safe. You can read more about this concept [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety)

Comment: That Wikipedia link doesn't fully explain what's going on here or why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply because `hash` value changes in the loop and your solution without intermediate temporary variable is not thread-safe. Consider that this method is invoked in several threads.

Say `thread-1` started `hash` computation and it is not `0` anymore. Some small moment later `thread-2` invokes the same method `hashCode()` on the same object and sees that `hash` is not `0`, but `thread-1` hasn't yet finished its computation. As the result, in the `thread-2` wrong `hash` (not fully computed) value will be used.

Answer (score 5):

It's a simple and cheap synchronization mechanism.

If a thread invokes hashCode() for the first time and a second thread invokes it again while the first thread is calculating the hash, the second thread would return an incorrect hash (an intermediate value of the calculation in the first thread) if using directly the attribute.

Comment: Note that the thread safety here does not prevent the hash from being calculated by more than one thread. Because there is no synchronization mechanism, there is no guarantee that a) two threads won't access `hash` while it's still `0`, nor b) that even after one thread does the caching that any other thread will see the result. Why is it thread safe despite maybe being calculated many times? Because the calculation is idempotent; no two threads can calculate different values.

Comment: Totally right, Lew. In that case, calculating twice the hash has a minor impact at the beginning compared with the benefit of not needing any synchronization mechanism during the life of the string.

Answer (score 2):

To put it very simple: local primitive `h` is well *local*; thus thread-safe; as opposed to `hash` which is shared.